# R multivariate interpolation - alternative to chebpol package

Tags: r

The **chebpol** package was archived on CRAN, so I'm looking for an alternative to
`chebpol::ipol(..., method = "polyharmonic")`.

I am trying to interpolate (and extrapolate) a function on a four-dimensional, regular, uniform grid with some points missing. The above mentioned `chebpol::ipol` function was perfect for that:

```r
known <- data.table::data.table(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  b = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  c = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4),
  d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
)
known[, score := a + b + c + d] # example values

f <- chebpol::ipol(
  val = known[, score], 
  knots = t(as.matrix(known[, c("a", "b", "c", "d")])),
  method = "polyharmonic"
)

f(c(1, 2, 4, 3)) # expected result: 10
```

How can I achieve the above without the **chebpol** package?

Comment: deleted my answer about installing from archive - I failed to install from source, perhaps these are the same "installation issues" for which the package was archived in the first place ("too few arguments to function ‘dgemm_’", perhaps from some change in BLAS API ... ?).  Have you tried `library("sos"); findFn("polyharmonic")` ?

Comment: @Ben thanks for the tip. I got two hits, one geospatial lidar package which is not applicable, and `tfaddons`, a tensorflow-addons package which might do what I need. I'd rather not add the entire tensorflow to my dependencies, but if that's the only way, I'll bite the bullet.

Comment: @BenBolker Does [this patch](https://github.com/jaganmn/attachments/blob/master/stack-overflow/2023-03-10/chebpol_2.1-2.patch) get things working under R-devel for you? In that case maybe we can salvage your deleted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @MikaelJagan there is now a patched version of this package available [here](https://github.com/bbolker/chebpol).  You should be able to install it with `remotes::install_github("bbolker/chebpol")`, provided you have development tools (compilers etc.) installed. (This is a forked version of the author's repository [here](https://github.com/sgaure/chebpol); I will submit a pull request, either before or after fixing a couple of other small check errors.)

Comment: I somehow managed to trick R into successfully installing the package directly from [this URL](https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/latest/src/contrib/Archive/chebpol/chebpol_2.1-2.tar.gz). I'll try if your version installs as well, as soon as I can. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if it installs OK on your system then you're done!  I can imagine there are subtleties of which compiler versions etc. that will determine whether installing from source works or not ...

Comment: @BrokenPhysics You will not be able to install from sources under R 4.3, to be released this spring. R 4.3 is stricter about C-level stuff in packages, and the maintainer did not adjust their source code to comply with the new rules, hence the archival. You should not have problems installing the archived versions from sources until you decide to upgrade.

Comment: The purpose of the patch is to make available a compliant version of **chebpol** that can be installed from sources even under R 4.3 (when it is released).

Answer (score 1):

For those using Mac OSX with M1/M2/M3 processors, in addition to applying Ben Bolker's solution, you must also modify the way R calls the compiler.

To do so, first install gcc:

```
brew install gcc
```

Then create this:

```
mkdir -p ~/.R    
touch ~/.R/Makevars
```

Then paste this into the Makevars file:

```
FLIBS = -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/VERSION/lib
```

You should be able to install the package in R using the Ben's patch:

```
remotes::install_github("bbolker/chebpol")
```

Cheers